# Python Dynamically subclass a base class containing the __init_subclass__ hook

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass

I am interested in using the new **init_subclass** hook provided in Python 3.6. See: [pep487](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/#proposal)

I have a class defined in exactly the same way as example provided within the aforementioned link (beneath Proposal). Now, I would like to dynamically subclass it using type like this:

```
class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, n, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.max_size = n*n


if __name__ == '__main__':

    dynamic_class = type('DerivedBase', (Base,), {'n':5})

    C = dynamic_class()

    print(C.max_size)
```

When I try this, I get:

```
c:\temp
λ python test_meta.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_meta.py", line 10, in <module>
    dynamic_class = type('DerivedBase', (Base,), {'n':5})
TypeError: __init_subclass__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'
```

Note that this works just fine, if I remove the n variable from the class definition and within the call to `type`.

Is this possible and if so, what is the syntax?

Comment: Wow, glad to find that I am not the only one having this issue after reading the doc of both `__init_subclass__` and `type`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the arguments to `__init_subclass__` in named parameters to the type call.

In this case, doing:

```
 dynamic_class = type('DerivedBase', (Base,), {}, n=5})
```

works.
Just take care that if you also use a metaclass, it should accept the extra parameters in `__new__` or `__init__` as well.

Comment: Thanks - when I glanced at the signature for type from an ipython prompt, it wasn't clear that it could accept named parameters like this.

Comment: My personal problem with this is that the keyword `metaclass` is grossly special and asymetric do any other keyword parameter, while not taking the usual `__` prefix and suffix.

Comment: @jsbueno Any clue why this isn't properly documented anywhere?